# Outlook email access via graphClient and proxy (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble retrieving email from a specified email address with password, I'm trying to use the graphClient because i cannot retrieve the email messages from the Exchange Web Services Server via Proxy.  I'm able to obtain a MSAL token fine, but when I try to obtain the result from the graphClient using the BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider I get 'Access is denied.'   I've tried the Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider but when I use that I get invalid token.  I could try the Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider, but that looks overly complex.

Roger Perkins

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
Imports System.Xml
Imports ActiveDirectory
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports Microsoft.Identity.Client
Imports Microsoft.Graph
Imports Azure.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions
Imports Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication
Imports System.Threading

Public Class EmailBL

    Public Class StaticClientWithProxyFactory
        Implements IMsalHttpClientFactory

        Private Shared ReadOnly s_httpClient As Http.HttpClient

        Shared Sub New()
            Dim webProxy = New WebProxy(New Uri("http://proxy:8XXX"), BypassOnLocal:=True)
            webProxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("proxyUser", "proxyPass")
            Dim proxyHttpClientHandler = New Http.HttpClientHandler With {.Proxy = webProxy, .UseProxy = True}
            s_httpClient = New Http.HttpClient(proxyHttpClientHandler)
        End Sub

        Private Function IMsalHttpClientFactory_GetHttpClient() As Http.HttpClient Implements IMsalHttpClientFactory.GetHttpClient
            Return s_httpClient
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class TokenProvider
        Implements IAccessTokenProvider

        Private Const client_id As String = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        Private Const tenant As String = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyy"
        Private Const scope As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" ' "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" ' "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" '

        ' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password?tabs=dotnet
        ' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory//develop/v2-oauth-ropc

        ReadOnly httpClientFactory As New StaticClientWithProxyFactory

        ReadOnly pcaOptions As New PublicClientApplicationOptions With {.ClientId = client_id, .TenantId = tenant}
        ReadOnly pca As IPublicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).WithHttpClientFactory(httpClientFactory).Build()

        Private Function IAccessTokenProvider_GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(uri As Uri, Optional additionalAuthenticationContext As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of String) Implements IAccessTokenProvider.GetAuthorizationTokenAsync

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

            'Dim testCache = pca.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToList()

            Dim ewsScopes = New String() {scope}
            'Dim authResult = Await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()

            Dim accessTokenTask As Task(Of AuthenticationResult)

            Try
                accessTokenTask = pca.AcquireTokenSilent(ewsScopes, "email@domain.com").ExecuteAsync()
            Catch ex As MsalUiRequiredException

            End Try

            Dim cred = New NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "emailPass") 

            accessTokenTask = pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, cred.UserName, cred.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync()

            Dim token = accessTokenTask.Result.AccessToken
            Return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(token)
        End Function

        Public ReadOnly Property AllowedHostsValidator As AllowedHostsValidator

        Private ReadOnly Property IAccessTokenProvider_AllowedHostsValidator As AllowedHostsValidator Implements IAccessTokenProvider.AllowedHostsValidator
            Get
                Throw New NotImplementedException()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class


    Public Function RetrieveEmails(ByRef sw As StreamWriter) As Integer

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Try

            ' token settings

            'Dim scopes = {"User.Read"}
            'Dim tenantId = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyy"
            'Dim clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            'Dim options = New UsernamePasswordCredentialOptions With {
            '    .AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            '}
            'Dim userName As String = "email@domain.com"
            'Dim password As String = "emailPass"
            'Dim userNamePasswordCredential = New UsernamePasswordCredential(userName, password, tenantId, clientId, options)

            ' proxy settings ' proxyAddress = "http://proxy:8XXX"

            Dim ProxyName As String = My.Settings.ProxyName
            Dim ProxyPort As String = My.Settings.ProxyPort

            Dim wproxy As New WebProxy(ProxyName, CInt(ProxyPort))
            wproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
            wproxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("proxyUser", "proxyPass")

            ' Dim authProvider = New Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes)

            Dim authProvider = New BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(New TokenProvider())

            Dim httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(proxy:=wproxy)
            Dim graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(httpClient, authProvider)


            ' Dim graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes)

            ' run query 

            'Dim result = graphClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync(
            '    Function(requestConfiguration) requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.[Select] Is New String() {"sender", "subject"})

            Dim result = graphClient.Users("email@domain.com").Messages.Count.GetAsync()

            result.Wait()

            ...
```

[image]

Tried BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider with TokenProvider, expected result, received Access is Denied.

Tried AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider with username/email address and password, expected result, received invalid token.

Comment: Try to look at your OAuth token with https://jwt.ms/ - it might have a wrong audience or wrong claims.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thanks, jwt.ms is handy, it appears I'm missing the Mail.Read scope.  Looks like if I change the dim result line to:
Dim result = graphClient.Users("email@domain.com").GetAsync() 
then I don't get an error.